# ValidateRequest=False can be conditional in asp.net webform?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have written below statement in my SamplePage.aspx file.

```
<%@ Page
    Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="SamplePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Holmes_Abel.CMS" **ValidateRequest="false"** %>
```

But i want SamplePage.aspx?validatereq=1 should set validaterequest property to true and SamplePage.aspx?validatereq=0 should set validaterequest property to false.

I doubt if we can achieve this.  If anyone having any suggestion in this regards, then please let me know about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer, You need to override IsValidRequestString method of RequestValidator class. You can write all conditional logic there.